# SQL Server Asymmetric Encryption Keys

Tags: encryption, asymmetric, sql-server

I have used SQL Server database with data to be encrypted and I will use symmetric key for encryption and will encrypt it by asymmetric key now comes the question how to give user permission to encrypt and not to decrypt

I have found this [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20151006062815/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lcris/archive/2006/01/13/sql-server-2005-example-for-how-to-allow-a-user-to-encrypt-but-not-decrypt.aspx) that propose creating two procedures and use them as security mechanism however my question here where is the public/private key thing of asymmetric encryption.

Are there any other solutions?

Comment: What version of SQL are you running?

Comment: I am using Sql Server 2012

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a series of stored procedures (specifically for MySQL vs. MSSQL) that might be of interest. You can view it at [sqlSec](https://github.com/jas-/sqlSec).

Keep in mind that it is more a proof of concept using stored procedures to rotate symmetric encryption keys but does provide a transparent encryption/decryption procedure examples in the readme.

Comment: Thanks for the references however I still didn't understand how that is really handled inside SQL Server

Comment: Why are you trying to do encryption in the database?  It's going to be 10 times easier to do your encryption in some language other than t-sql that interacts as a client rather than on the sql server directly.